# Yoneda lemma for endofunctors

Tags: category-theory, programming, yoneda-lemma

The Yoneda lemma deals with functors *to* the category of functions.

The Yoneda functor, say **Y**, for an object, say **Z**, is a specific example of such a functor.

The lemma establishes a one-to-one correspondence between natural transformations from the Yoneda functor **Y**, for an object **Z**, to functors, **F**, to the category of functions, and elements of **F(Z)**.

Clearly the Yoneda lemma is pointful (it involves elements of sets).

Now assume that there exists a functor *from* the category of functions to the category.
This functor can be composed with Yoneda functors to obtain endofunctors. Functional programming is a typical area where this is the case.

My questions are:

1. Does there exist a pointfree alternative of the Yoneda lemma for endofunctors?
2. What are the minimal extra requirements on the category that are needed to prove it?

Thanks, Luc